# Riding an Abra at Night (Dubai)

Tags: dubai, night-transport, riverboats

[Abras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abra_%28boat%29) are small Arabic fishing boats and I am informed that Dubai has a cottage industry of using these boats to transport visitors across the [Dubai Creek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubai_Creek).

Is it reasonable to expect one or more boat operators to be running after working hours?  Or more succinctly, are these boats available on a 24 hour basis?  Also, and critically, are there times, like [Ramadan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan), when they do not work? Or similar occasions where taking an Abra ride might be inappropriate or disrespectful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Dubai Online](http://www.dubai-online.com/videos/video-dubai-souk-abra-station/):

- Deira Old Souk Abra Station (Deira) to (Bur Dubai) – 5 am to midnight
- Sabkha Abra Station (Deira) to Dubai Old Souk Abra Station (Bur Dubai) – 24 hours

Comment: Ramadan? other holidays?

Comment: People do not stop working in Ramadan, timings could be different a bit, I did not manage to get a source anyway.